# Calculate limit using Riemann integral

Tags: integration, limits

Some of the limits are easy to see, but I want to use Riemann integral to determine the value of the following limits.

1. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n}\right)$
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+n)}$
3. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sin {\frac{n}{n^2+1^2}}+\sin {\frac{n}{n^2+2^2}}+\cdots+\sin {\frac{n}{n^2+n^2}}\right)$

---

For example in first, I suppose $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ is equal to the limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n}\right) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{2n} \frac{1}{n+i} \\&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i = 1}^{2n} f\left(a+\frac{(b-a)i}{2n}\right)\cdot\frac{(b-a)i}{n}
\end{align}
But cannot find anything.

Please don't tell me the method directly, I would appreciate it if you could give me some crucial hints for one\all of them. Thank you very much.

Comment: @experimentX typo fixed

Comment: the first looks like equal to $\displaystyle \int_0^2 \frac{1}{1+x}dx$

Comment: @experimentX it would be great if you hint me on how to think about it rather than giving the result. Thanks :)

Comment: the third one looks like $\sin \theta \approx \theta $ as $\theta \to 0$, but as previous ones ... I am not sure.

Comment: does the last one converge to $\pi \over 4$ ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second $ \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+n)} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left( \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)\left( 1 + \frac 2 n \right) ... \left( 1 + \frac{n}{n}\right)\right)^{\frac 1 n}$ which is equal to $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty } e^{ \frac 1 n  \sum_{k=1}^n\log \left( 1 + \frac k n \right)}$

Comment: I agree with what you write so far, but I think it can be further simplified. You didn't use Riemann integral so far. Can you help me further?

Comment: this part $ \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty } { \frac 1 n  \sum_{k=1}^n\log \left( 1 + \frac k n \right)} = \int_0^1 \log(1+x) dx $

Answer (score 2):

For the first, rewrite $\dfrac{1}{n+k}$ as $\dfrac{1}{n}\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$, and bring the common $\dfrac{1}{n}$ in front.

Kind of looks like a Riemann sum, step size $\dfrac{1}{n}$, integrating $\dots$ from $0$ to $\dots$. (I could fill in the $\dots$, but so can you.)

Answer (score 2):

The $3$rd limit is straightforward by Taylor series and then Riemann sum 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+(k/n)^2} + O\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}\right)^3\right)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: hahaha .. thank you :)

Comment: @experimentX: it was my pleasure. ;)

Comment: How do you find the bounds for the integral?